# Can I run an app built with .net framework 4.7 on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-xp, .net-framework, .net-4.5

Im building a vb.net WPF application on Visual Studio. The app targets .Net framework 4.7.
Some of my customers might run my app on their Windows XP machine. According to Microsoft XP doesn't support .Net framework 4.5 and later. So I was wondering if XP allows my application to run on itself. If yes will it run like it would run on Windows 7 or later? If not generally what changes can one make to make the application run properly on XP?

Answer (score 4):

No. XP does not support much beyond .NET 4. XP cannot be updated any more either.

I checked my own XP machines and it only goes as far as V4 Full.

So you need to make the APP work with V4 Full, or else upgrade the operating system.

Comment: I'd make them update. There is absolutely no reason whatsoever to be supporting customers who will not update an OS that went end of life almost 7 years ago.